# How do i use Facebook API to post only on my page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

As i understand, i need to validate my person, wait for my app review etc.
But what if i just need to post only on my page and nowhere else? Someone told me that i just have to be an app and page administrator and i even can leave app in dev mode but it didn't work for me. In all cases i just recieve

> If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and either publish_to_groups permission with user token, or both manage_pages and publish_pages permission with page token; If posting to a page, requires both manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permission

Is it any way to skip all these checks and use API for posting? If not, can you tell me some free services i can use to reach this with? Much thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are posting to a page (any page) you need a token with `manage_pages` and `publish_page`.

You can generate a test token using the explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ - but this token is short lived (1h)

Using the short term token in the explorer, you can get a list of your pages (endpoint: `/me/accounts`) that you manage and that list will contain a `page_token` for each page you manage.

With that `page_token` you can post to the page.

You can put the `page_token` into the Access token debugger to see it's permissions.
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

You need approvals if you are putting the app live and allowing non-developers access to it.

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. But the problem is that i am the only person who see these posts. People see posts that i publish by myself but they don't see anything that i've posted using this method

Comment: The app itself still needs to be "live".

Comment: So, if app is in dev mode i can't post even to my own page, right?

Comment: You can, but no one will see it. But it can be in live mode without getting approval for extended permissions if no one else uses them.

Comment: Seems like not. I switched app to live, then got an access token. I used it to ask /me/accounts and it returned an access token for my page. But i still can not use to post anything (still getting the same error)